# Как реализовать анимацию инициализации RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Необходимо реализовать анимацию инициализации для Recycler с GridLayoutManager. В сети много примеров с переопределением методов RecyclerView. Это есдинственный способ ее реализации? Мне необходимо чтобы айтемы из нижней точки экрана как из одной колоды сдвинулись в соответствующие ячейки Grid. Подскажите направление куда копать, не могу найти подходящих решений.

Comment: А что вы конкретно реализуете? RecyclerView не предназначен для подобных анимаций: во время анимации пользователь может сделать например скроллинг и все дочерние элементы поменяют ячейки и т.п.